# Are there available web parts or solutions for idea management?

Tags: web-part

We are currently evaluating sharepoint based idea management as an alternative to full-fledged solutions such as Hype software. (as we are just starting to evaluate, please excuse if I am not using the right terminology suitable for sharepoint).

What we would like to have:
Users can submit ideas, which can be commented on, voted on, and evaluated with simple workflows. Gamification is nice, and so is "reporting".

Where would be a good place to find web parts that can do this?

Comment: I'm after the same thing. Did you end up coming up with anything? Please let me know!

Comment: We spoke with Microsoft, and they have done Idea Management projects for customers, but nothing "out of the box" or as "plugin" that's available easily.